# Eclipse plugin - accessing the editor

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, editor

So, I’m currently developing a plugin for the eclipse IDE. In a nutshell, the plugin is a collaborative real time code editor where the editor is eclipse (which is something like Google documents but with the code and on eclipse). Meaning that when I install the plugin, I would be able to connect -using my Gmail account- eclipse to the partner’s eclipse. And when I start coding on my machine, my partner would be seeing what I write and vice versa.

The problem I’m currently facing is accessing eclipse’s editor. For example, I have to monitor all the changes in the active document so that every time a change happens, the other partner’s IDE would be notified with this change.

I found and read about the **IDcoumentProvider**, **IDocument** and **IEditorInput** classes and they’re somehow connected but I can’t understand this connection or how to use it. So if someone can explain this connection I would really appreciate it. Also if there is another way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the `IEditorPart` via the `IWorkbenchPage`.

```
IEditorPart editor =  ((IWorkbenchPage) PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
        .getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage()).getActiveEditor();
```

From there, you have access to various other classes, including the editor's `IEditorInput`, the `File` loaded by that editor, or the underlying GUI `Control` element. (Note that depending on the kind of editor (text files, diagram, etc.) you may have to cast to different classes.)

```
FileEditorInput input = (FileEditorInput) editor.getEditorInput();
StyledText editorControl = ((StyledText) editor.getAdapter(Control.class));
String path = input.getFile().getRawLocationURI().getRawPath();
```

Now, you can add a listener to the `Control`, e.g. a `KeyAdapter` for monitoring all key strokes occurring in the respective editor.

```
editorControl.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Editing in file " + path);
    }
});
```

Or, if monitoring all key strokes is too much, you can register an `IPropertyListener` to the editor. This listener will e.g. be notified whenever the editor gets 'dirty' or when it is saved. The meaning of `propId` can be found in `IWorkbenchPartConstants`.

```
editor.addPropertyListener(new IPropertyListener() {
    @Override
    public void propertyChanged(Object source, int propId) {
        if (propId == IWorkbenchPartConstants.PROP_DIRTY) {
            System.out.println("'Dirty' Property Changed");
        }
    }
});
```