# Eclipse Plugin Development: How to access code written in the eclipse editor

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, code-editor

I'm making an Eclipse plug-in that requires access to code written in the Eclipse editor. I've followed the process mentioned in the link. 
[Accessing Eclipse editor code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115154/eclipse-plugin-accessing-the-editor)
But it's showing filepath instead of code in the message box. The *getEditorInput()* of *IEditorEditor* class isn't doing what it should do according to the link. Here's my code. Please help me find what i'm doing wrong.

```
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);

    IEditorPart editor = ((IWorkbenchPage) PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
            .getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage()).getActiveEditor();

    IEditorInput input = (IEditorInput) editor.getEditorInput();     // accessing code from eclipse editor

    String code = input.toString();

    MessageDialog.openInformation(
            window.getShell(),
            "Project",
            code);

    return null;
}
```

And here's snap of the output.
[image]

Comment: [_"`IEditorInput` is a light weight descriptor of editor input, like a file name but more abstract. It is not a model."_](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IEditorInput.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get text from active editor in Eclipse PDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897938/how-to-get-text-from-active-editor-in-eclipse-pde)

Comment: It is the `StyledText` that contains the text being edited - you have missed out the `getAdapter` line

Comment: @greg-449 Didn't think it'd be in there. Careless of me. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @howlger Other links you provided didn't work for me.

Comment: My first link explains what you actually see. The second link (possible duplicate) explains how to get to the file content as a stream. The answer by @nitlind is how to get the content of the displayed editor even if the editor is dirty (not saved). If none of this works for you, then tell us what exactly you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this two different ways. This way works regardless of whether the contents are backed by a file on disk or not.

This method gets the text `IDocument` from the editor, which is how the contents are stored and accessed for most uses. `StyledText` is a widget, and unless you are doing something with Widgets and Controls, it's not the right way in. For that you're going to go from the editor part, through the `ITextEditor` interface, and then use the `IDocumentProvider` with the current editor input. This is skipping the `instanceof` check you'd want to do beforehand, as well as anything you might have to do if this is a page in a `MultiPageEditorPart` (there's no standard way for handling those).

```
org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocument document = 
    ((org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ITextEditor)editor).
    getDocumentProvider().
    getDocument(input);
```

You can get, and modify, the contents through the `IDocument`.