# Eclipse RCP: Get current text from editor, even if it is not saved

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin in which I'm trying to get the text from the current open editor, I can do that using this code:

```
IFile file = ((FileEditorInput) editorInput).getFile();
InputStream inputStream = file.getContents();
String result = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
```

But looks like it only returns the state of the file when it is saved, if I have that file open in the editor and make some changes I want to get this latest state, not the one when it was saved, is there any API I can use for that?

Comment: Likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/50719777/27905 .

Comment: With this code >  `editor.getTextViewer().getDocument().get()`